# Dump :node object in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am a dev tasked with making some changes to the cookbooks owned by the devops team. We don't have access to knife or the chef server.

I tried to add some debugging to an existing chef recipe

```
members = search(
    :node,
    search_str,
    filter_result: {
      'name' => ['name'],
    }

#
# print statements NOT working as expected
#
p ":node=" + :node.to_s     # <--- prints ":node=node"
pp :node.to_s               # <--- prints "node"
pp :node                    # <--- prints :node
```

Is it possible to dump the entire json structure of the :node object? Any workarounds. I want to see the structure of the :node object to debug the search() call as the search isn't working as expected.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:node` in ruby is a [symbol](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_symbols.html), not a variable. Symbols always start with colon (`:`). For starters you can think of them as of immutable strings. That is why you get such output. You just print a lot of strings.

What you actually need is just `node`:

```rb
pp "node:", node
```

But beware, `node` is a huge object with a lot of attributes.

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Been struggling with this for so many hours.